# "Settle for" or "settle on"?

Tags: word-usage

> I was looking for a good contraceptive. In the end I settled **for** the pill.
>
> I was looking for a good contraceptive. In the end I settled **on** the pill.

Which one is the right option?

Comment: They mean different things. It is impossible to say which is right without additional context.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"Settled for" implies that one is making a compromise; "settled on" just means that one has made a final decision.

The relevant definitions are:

> [settle for something](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/settle_1#settle_1__153)
> to accept something that is not exactly what you want but is the best that is available
>
> [settle on something](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/settle_1#settle_1__166)
> to choose or make a decision about something after thinking about it

Comment: So I should use *settled on* in this case?

Comment: That depends on the nature of your choice: if you made the decision as an "these side effects are better than the other ones" you likely settled *for* that contraception as the least-bad compromise: ie you accepted the negatives but it wasn't perfect. If you just had a think and decided you preferred that one, you likely settled *on* that contraception. The difference is that settling "for" something implies it was choosing the least bad, not the most good.

Comment: I don't like _settled on_ at all. Use _settled for_ if you were concerned about tradeoffs, as @Jon says. If not, avoid _settle on_, and use a verb like _chose_ or _picked_ or _opted for_.

Comment: Settled on is a perfectly acceptable use, although I'd also perhaps add that it tends to be used when the decision has taken a while to make